# How do you get an additional participant attached like in the picture attached

Tags: process, business-process-management, bpmn

I'm looking to get the additional participant to appear as in the [picture](http://www.activiti.org/userguide/images/bpmn.boundary.error.example.png)
[image]

Comment: I don't see any participants in that image.

Answer (score 1):

The image provided in the link mentioned by you is actually an example in activiti explorer and if you are facing any issue in designing the process you can refer to the Review Sales Lead example process in activiti explorer and download xml from it. It will be great if you can provide some more details to know what problem you are exactly facing.